# Fit title and image exactly in shinydashboard header

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

How can I make title and image to fit in exactly in shiny dashboard header space?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader()
anchor <- tags$a(href='http://www.example.com',
                 tags$img(src='logo.png', height='60', width='50'),
                 'project name')

header$children[[2]]$children <- tags$div(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".name { background-color: black }"))),
  anchor,
  class = 'name')

ui <- dashboardPage(header, dashboardSidebar(), dashboardBody())

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output, session) {})
```